# Combining sorted files with fifos

Tags: performance, bash, fifo

I have some sorted, gzipped files in a directory. How do I combine some of them into another sorted, gzipped file? Right now I'm using explicit fifos. Is there a way to do it in bash without? I'm a bit of a bash noob, so please excuse my lack of style.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Invocation ./merge [files ... ]
# Turns an arbitrary set of sorted, gzipped files into a single sorted, gzipped file,
# printed to stdout. Redirect this script's output!
for f in $@
do
    mkfifo $f.raw
    gzcat $f > $f.raw &
    # sort -C $f.raw
done
sort -mu *.raw | gzip -c # prints to stdout.
rm -f *.raw
```

I'm looking to convert this into something like...

```
sort -mu <(gzcat $1) <(gzcat $2) <(gzcat $3) ... | gzip -9c # prints to stdout.
```

...but don't know how. Do I need a loop building the parameters to string? Is there some sort of magic shortcut for this? Maybe `map gzcat $@`?

NOTE: Each of the files is in excess of 10GB (and 100GB unzipped). I have a 2TB drive, so this isn't really a problem. Also, this program MUST run in O(n) or it becomes unfeasible.

Comment: I see you edited the question while I was answering - yes, you need a loop to build the command string, and either `eval` or `bash -c "$cmd"` to execute it at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine `eval` and 'process substitution' with Bash.  Assuming the basic file names don't contain spaces (which, given that you use `$@` instead of `"$@"` is probably the case), then something like:

```
cmd="sort -mu"
for file in "$@"
do cmd="$cmd <(gzip -cd $file)"
done
eval $cmd | gzip -c9 > outputfile.gz
```

You can also use `bash -c "$cmd"` instead of `eval $cmd` on the last line.  If there are spaces in the file names, you have to work a bit harder.  This works if the names don't contain single quotes:

```
cmd="sort -mu"
for file in "$@"
do cmd="$cmd <(gzip -cd '$file')"
done
eval $cmd | gzip -c9 > outputfile.gz
```

With single quotes in the file names too, you have to work a lot harder.

Answer (score 1):

For me, your question is a little unclear, but if I understand your need, try this:

```
gunzip -c file1 file2 .... | sort | gzip -9 > mergedFile.gz
```

If you want to do all files of a certain type in 1 dir, then you can use `file*.type` as the input list to gunzip, otherwise, per my example, you'll need to list each file explicitly.

The `-c` option indicates 'send output to stdout', which is the read by the pipe, sent to `sort`, which sends its output to stdout, the pipe, and into gzip, with it's stdout being redirected into the final file. The `-9` is the highest compress, which gives you the smallest file (for gzip), but takes longer. You can give an explicit number between -1 and -9 to tune the compression size/time to compress trade off for your needs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I really want to use sort -mu, which won't work if we gunzip in one go. It turns sort from O(nlogn) into O(n).

Comment: I'd normally use an explicit `gzip -c -9`, but I guess that will work.

Comment: So you have large files and you're looking for a way to parallelize the process by pre-sorting smaller files and then merging them at the end? And you have multi-CPUs that you can assign to each smaller sort process? Are you looking to save time, or CPU, or ??? There are significant number of people interested in performance tuning here on S.O. You might add tag for benchmarking, testing, performance-tuning to get better advice on how to approach this. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Done. Thanks. But I was more looking for a robust way of building fifos (that can't be broken by a touch [file].raw) than for tuning the performance. Maybe something like command substitution? http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156?page=0,1

Comment: OK, That's an interesting question, but I wish that had been in your original question. I've never had to face that, so I don't have a good answer. I suppose putting 600 permissions on the fifo is not enough? How would 'touch'ing the file happen? Can you make your fifo name more unique, adding  the processID ($$) to the name?  What happened to your concern about O(nlogn) vs O(n)? Good night.

Comment: That won't work. `sort -mu` only performs a merge of pre-sorted files. If you gzcat several files then pipe that into `sort`, sort only sees one very large file, and `sort -mu` becomes a nop.

Answer (score 1):

> With single quotes in the file names too, you have to work a lot harder.

Here's a way to escape single quotes within file names (or file paths) that will get `eval`'ed in variables surrounded by single quotes.

```
(
esc="'\''"
file="/Applications/iWork '09/Pages.app"
file="${file//\'/${esc}}"
#echo "'${file}'"; ls -bdl "'${file}'"
evalstr="echo '${file}'; ls -bdl '${file}'"
#set -xv
eval "${evalstr}"
)
```